# keeping django models clean method validating foreign key object and using ModelForm save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

In my model's `clean` method I validate if given in foreign key exhibitor is_premium and also validate that he does not have more then MAX_DISCOUNTS_PER_EXHIBITOR active objects.

It works perfectly fine in django admin. Both when adding as well when editing.

I would like to get it working in my custom (non-django-admin) views. I am using ModelForms.

## first approach

I assign exhibitor in view, to initially `commit=False` saved object.

And it crashes with `DoesNotExist`: Discount has no exhibitor, because `clean` is executed, but exhibitor is not yet assigned. What should be the proper way of implementing it?

## models.py

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    exhibitor = models.ForeignKey(
        'core_backend.Exhibitor', related_name='discounts')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=u"Aktywny")
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name=u"Tytuł")

    def clean(self):

        if not self.exhibitor.is_premium:
            raise ValidationError(
                u'Discounts only for premium')

        count = Discount.objects.filter(
            is_active=True,
            exhibitor=self.exhibitor
        ).count()

        if not self.pk:
            # newly added
            count = count + (1 if self.is_active else 0)
        else:
            # edited
            discount = Discount.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if discount.is_active and not self.is_active:
                count = count - 1
            elif not discount.is_active and self.is_active:
                count = count + 1

        if count > settings.MAX_DISCOUNTS_PER_EXHIBITOR:
            raise ValidationError(
                u'Max %s active discounts' % (
                    settings.MAX_DISCOUNTS_PER_EXHIBITOR
                )
            )
```

## forms.py

```
class DiscountForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Discount
        fields = (
            'title',
            'description',
            'is_activa',
        )
```

## views.py

```
def add_discount(request, fair_pk, exhibitor_pk):
    fair = get_object_or_404(Fair, pk=fair_pk)
    exhibitor = get_object_or_404(
        Exhibitor, fair=fair, pk=exhibitor_pk, user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'GET':

        form = DiscountForm()

        return render(request, 'new_panel/add_discount.html', {
            'exhibitor': exhibitor,
            'discount_form': form,
        })

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DiscountForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            discount = form.save(commit=False)
            discount.exhibitor = exhibitor
            discount.save()
            return redirect(reverse(
                'discounts_list',
                kwargs={"fair_pk": fair.pk, 'exhibitor_pk': exhibitor.pk}
            ))
        return render(request, 'new_panel/add_discount.html', {
            'exhibitor': exhibitor,
            'discount_form': form,
        })
```

### Second approach

I was trying also different approach with separate form used for POST, but it crashes with same error:

## forms.py

```
class DiscountFormAdd(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Discount
        fields = (
            'title',
            'exhibitor',
            'is_active',
        )

    def __init__(self, exhibitor, *args, **kwargs):
        self.exhibitor = exhibitor
        super(DiscountFormAdd, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=False):
        discount = super(DiscountFormAdd, self).save(commit=False)
        discount.exhibitor = self.exhibitor

        if commit:
            discount.save()

        return discount
```

## views.py

```
def add_discount(request, fair_pk, exhibitor_pk):
    fair = get_object_or_404(Fair, pk=fair_pk)
    exhibitor = get_object_or_404(
        Exhibitor, fair=fair, pk=exhibitor_pk, user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'GET':

        form = DiscountForm()

        return render(request, 'new_panel/add_discount.html', {
            'exhibitor': exhibitor,
            'discount_form': form,
        })

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DiscountFormAdd(data=request.POST, exhibitor=exhibitor)

        if form.is_valid():
            discount = form.save(commit=True)

            return redirect(reverse(
                'discounts_list',
                kwargs={"fair_pk": fair.pk, 'exhibitor_pk': exhibitor.pk}
            ))
        return render(request, 'new_panel/add_discount.html', {
            'exhibitor': exhibitor,
            'discount_form': form,
        })
```

I would like to stick with model clean validation, rather than jumping into forms clean. If django admin is able to do it, then it is surely possible to implemented in custom modelforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning exhibitor using `self.exhibitor = exhibitor`, this sets a `property` on your form which has nothing to do with the content for the form.

To *actually* set the exhibitor, use the following code instead:

```
import copy
.
.
.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # request.POST is an immutable QueryDict so it needs to be copied
        form_data = copy.copy(request.POST)
        form_data['exhibitor'] = exhibitor.id
        form = DiscountFormAdd(data=form_data)
```

and entirely drop setting the `exhibitor` inside your form's `__init__`

This way, your form's data (which is used to create your `Discount`) object will be correct and can be cleaned

[Edit]
How to create a hidden input field in a ModelForm:

```
class DiscountFormAdd(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DiscountFormAdd, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['exhibitor'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    ...
```

or you can also use the `widgets` attribute of the Meta class

```
class DiscountFormAdd(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Discount
        widgets = {'exhibitor': forms.HiddenInput()}
        ...
```

Comment: how should the form class look like? I dont want to display in UI the exhibitor

Comment: You can use a hidden input widget https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to hide a form field from a ModelForm